# VB.NET Split certain part of string and display it in Textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, split

This is the example of the text
(for example this text is on the textbox)
34CDBED1CA08 nheK9M15pqprtwyl

I want to split it and put 34CDBED1CA08 in the text box and format it with ":" every 2 digit like this 34:CD:BE:D1:CA:08

and put this nheK9M15pqprtwyl in the other textbox

Comment: Please give examples on top of a more _general requirement_. Something like "Split every two characters with : within first 12 ....."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to create a mac address and that the length of the first part of your string should always be split at 12 characters.

```
    Dim input as String = txtInput.Text
    Dim textbox1 as String = ""
    Dim textbox2 as String = ""

    textbox1 = input.Substring(0,12)

    For i as Integer = 0 to 4
        textbox1 = textbox1.Insert(2+(i*3), ":")
    Next

    textbox2 = input.substring(12)

    txtTextBox1.Text = textbox1
    txtTextBox2.Text = textbox2
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAalT7

Comment: thanks but i got an error on your code
the only error is pointing at the variable i and said  Error 1 Variable 'I' hides a variable in an enclosing block. C:\Users\Rayan Babasa Talion\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Snipe Mac\Snipe Mac\Form1.vb 45 17 Snipe Mac

Comment: @AngeloTalion Are you already using a variable 'i' somwhere else in your code?

Comment: im sorry it's ok now i forgot it already use it :) thanks i will try to run

Comment: i already run it. no errors but the format of the mac address in not correct this is the output 
34:::::CDBED1CA08